# javascript validation for register page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I don't know what's wrong in this. Validation not working here.
Form submitted without validation.

```
function validate()
{

        if( document.myForm.username.value == "" )
            {
            alert( "Please provide your user name!" );
                document.myForm.fname.focus() ;
                return false;
                }

                if( document.myForm.email.value == "" )
                    {
                        alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
                        document.myForm.email.focus() ;
                        return false;
                    }
                            if (!(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/).test(document.myform.email.value))  
                                {  
                                    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")  
                                    return false;   
                                    }   

                    }

return false;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="myForm" action=" " name="myForm" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="text-center">Register Information</p>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="control-label col-xs-2">UserName</label>

        <div class="col-xs-2">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="username" 
                placeholder="UserName">

        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="email" class="control-label col-xs-2">Email Address</label>

        <div class="col-xs-2">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
                placeholder="abc@domain.com" />

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="password" class="control-label col-xs-2">Password</label>

        <div class="col-xs-2">

            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"
                placeholder="##########" />

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">

            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

I don't know whats wrong in this.Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Wheres your javascript?

Comment: Are  you talking about HTML5 validation ?

Comment: now i add the java script i used.it poped the error message but doesn't effect on form submission

Answer (score 0):

Try using type="email" form email id field validation and 'required' directive for required fields.

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="abc@domain.com" required/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to do validation using HTML5 features you have to add attrributes like required or pattern to your inputs.

You trigger validate() on submit bu there is no javascript code in the markup you pasted.

Start with this article.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

It describes native browser support for valdiation and later suggests some libraries and examples of custom code.

Answer (score 0):

In validate function the closing bracket just before the last "return false" statement is unnecessary.